# How to bind Alt-p to up arrow instead of π

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

Mac binds alt-p and alt-n to π and ˜.  How to make it behave as up and down arrow?

Answer (score 1):

Normally we use `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file to customize some keys.

```
{
    "~p" = "moveUp:";
    "~n" = "moveDown:"; /* not really works */
}
```

However I found it does not work for alt-n.

Would you consider to use ctrl-p and ctrl-n instead? It is of standard emacs/readline key combination.

Comment: yes. M-n doesn't work.  and the binding seems doesn't work under intellij (which is not cocoa).

Comment: DefaultKeyBinding.dict only works for cocoa. If you want to set a global key combination, try Karabiner.

Comment: Quite: CTRL p and n are already set to work as up and down arrows - that's the Unix standard. Any reason that you particularly want Alt p and n instead?